# DeployError: Provided address is invalid,the capitalization checksum test failed,or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment

I have the following code:

```
var account = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x249eb..")
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

let Contr = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {from: account, gas: 47000, data: bytecode})

await  Contr.deploy({ data: bytecode }).send({ from: account, gas: '1500000', gasPrice: '30000000000000'})
    .then(function(newContractInstance){ console.log(newContractInstance) });
```

And I am getting the following error when I try to `deploy().send()` the contract:

```
Script failed: Error: Provided address "[object Object]" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.
```

The provided address is the same one than the one used for getting the contract Contr by `new web3.eth.Contract` but, in this case, I dont get any error and the output is correct.

I have been checking another questions related with this error and I didnt get any solution.

I tried with `account`, `accounts[0]`, and the address directly '0x249..'. I am using web3 1.0.0. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you make the first line explicitly synchronous, ie:
```var account = await web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x249eb..")```

Comment: @AnAllergyToAnalogy It is the same error result

Comment: Can you console.log(account) immediately before the deploy line?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct account: `0x249eb..`

Comment: From the code you've provided it's hard to see precisely where it's happening, but from this part ```Provided address "[object Object]"```, it seems like you're passing a Javascript object where a string (with the address) should be. It's implicitly converting the object to the string "[object Object]" and then that isn't an address obviously. Are you omitting anything from the code you provided?

Comment: I also tried adding .toString() and nothing happens.. I think I am not omitting relevant code, just how I get the abi and bytecode:

`let code = fs.readFileSync('Contr.sol').toString();
    let compiledCode = solc.compile(code);
    let abi = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Contr'].interface);
    let bytecode = compiledCode.contracts[':Contr'].bytecode;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some superfluous (and incorrectly placed) data on this line:

`let Contr = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {from: account, gas: 47000, data: bytecode})`

your code should execute correctly if you change it to

`let Contr = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)`

as the deploy line takes care of the from account, the gas and the bytecode.

The `new web3.eth.Contract` function takes the following arguments [(as per the docs)](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html):

`new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, address, options)`

So it was interpreting this object: `{from: account, gas: 47000, data: bytecode}` as the address for a previously deployed instance of your contract.